# Django: How to use local copy of base theme?

Tags: python, django

I am working in Django 1.10, and have inherited a project. The `base.html` template extends a theme template that is not included in the project:

```
{% extends "theme_base.html" %}
```

It seems there is another base theme repo, which is specified via a github URL in the requirements file. This all works seamlessly.

I now want to make a minor text change to the base theme, but I'm not sure how to do this and test the change locally.

I have checked out a copy of the theme repo locally, and installed it with:

```
pip install -U -e ../dc_base_theme
```

But when I make changes in that local repo, they don't appear in my running Django site on localhost.

How do I make sure my Django repo is pointing to that local copy of the theme?

Comment: Can you describe what element you want to change ?

Comment: @RajaSimon It's just a minor text change in the base theme, I've made it locally, but I'm not seeing it since I guess my template is still looking at the base template in the version of the theme installed via requirements, not the local copy.

Comment: Make sure you have restarted your server after installing the package/modifying the theme.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, tried that.

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough information to debug the problem. The template used will depend on your `TEMPLATES` setting, and your `INSTALLED_APPS` (if you have `'APP_DIRS': True,`). If you change a view so that it uses a template that does not exist, then the debug page will show you which directories Django tried. You might find that useful to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

is the `theme_base.html`  file in the project folder correclty? 
for example, if you have a subfolders you shoud use it like:

```
{% extends 'template/theme_base.html' %}
```

Comment: It doesn't exist in this project at all, yet it renders OK. It's in the other repo. It's being pulled in mysteriously somehow.